# Youtube API - Paging issue

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

we using this API: google-api-services-youtube-v3-rev20221108-2.0.0.jar
to get the list of the channels:
this is the request we send:

```
YouTube.Search.List searchList =youtubeService.search().list("snippet");
searchList.setMaxResults(50);
searchList.setQ("channelName");
searchList.setType(Collections.singletonList("channel"));
searchList.setPageToken("nextPageToken");
```

the issue with the paging: for example: I get from the response: totalResult = 530should be 11 pages. But after 4 pages I get nextPageToken nullwhy? please can you give me the way for the paging in this API?

try to get the list of the channels,
the issue with the paging:
for example: i get from the response: totalResult = 530
should be 11 pages.
But after 4 pages I get nextPageToken null

Comment: [`pageInfo.totalResults`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#pageInfo.totalResults) *Please note that the value is an approximation and may not represent an exact value.*